# Recaptcha does not display on localhost

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, recaptcha

I installed Contact Form 7 Simple Recaptcha plugin for my wordpress project.  I have added the keys and I have added the following to my form:

```
[cf7sr-simple-recaptcha]
```

But Recaptcha does not display for my form.

Any ideas on how I can make the recaptcha to work locally?

Comment: can you please add your code so we can understand the question